# Скопировать стили элемента

Tags: jquery, css

Есть ли `jquery` плагин, с помощью которого можно скопировать стили одного элемента в другой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А что мешает взять название класса элемента и добавить/заменить этот класс в другом элементе?

```
$('slector_1').addClass($('slector_2').attr('class'));
```

Понятное дело, что если стили были заданы через ID элемента, то этот фокус не пройдет. Но это уже как бы ваша недоработка. Решений такой задачи, я в инете не встречал, т.к. мало кто занимается таким извращением )) Попробовал сам набросать вам примерчик, который, я надеюсь, отвернет вас от такого подхода. Посмотреть результат и испугаться можно [тут](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/pDFRL/). После просмотра представьте, как это замечательно будет добавлять к другому элементу. ;)

**HTML**

```
<div class="with_css">Кликни меня</div>
<div id="res"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.with_css {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #900;
    background-color: #FFFF00;
}
```

**JS**

```
var styles, arrStyle, styleName, i, j;
$('.with_css').click(function(){
    styles = window.getComputedStyle ? getComputedStyle(this, '') : this.currentStyle;
    for(i = 0; i < styles.length; i++){
        arrStyle = styles[i].split('-');
        styleName = arrStyle[0];
        for(j = 1; j < arrStyle.length; j++){
            styleName +=  arrStyle[j].slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + arrStyle[j].slice(1);
        }
        if(styles[styleName]){
            $('#res').append(styles[i] + ': ' + styles[styleName] + '; <br />');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @Iranda, если можно, то не изменяйте текст ссылки, т.к. есть новички, которые, как показала практика, не всегда замечают её, если она имеет вид аля [тут](http://hashcode.ru/questions/124743#124744). Именно поэтому, я стал писать адрес в качестве текста ссылки